# How to read table data from non-default database in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

My django project uses 2 databases, 1 existing database and another one which I am creating through my project using Models. I have defined db's in settings.py as below :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'music': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myMusicDb.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I generated model data using inspectdb command and everything works fine if I remove the default db from settings.py and make the 'music' db the default db. My query is how to keep both db in settings.py and to work with both DataBases ? Is there any way to tell django to use specific database from settings.py ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/.
We can either use routers or we can make use of using keyword in query such as -

```
Album.objects.using('music').all()
```

Thought to post it, may be it could help someone.